# What do brown and red folders mean in PhpStorm / SVN?

Tags: svn, phpstorm

We have PhpStorm 10 and use SVN on Windows.

[image]

- a colleague and I noticed that the folders in the common SVN project that we have different colored folders, some brown, some red, but not the same ones are brown for him as are brown for me
- when **I** paste in a file from Windows explorer to a **brown** folder, it asks if I want to track it in SVN
- when **my colleague** pastes in a file from Windows explorer to a **brown** folder, it marks it to track in SVN without asking (not correct)
- when **both he and I** paste in files to the **red** folder, it doesn't ask us if we want to add them to SVN
- I have another folder which is marked to not check in files to SVN (below "sandbox") but its **text is gray** so it seems the brown and red colors of the folders have different meanings than to hide form SVN

[image]

**What is the significance of these brown and red folders, and how do we change them so we can get the folders to have the same colors and always ask if we want to track files added in SVN?**

Answer (score 6):

- "Brown" folder is ordinary folder
- "Red" is folder that was excluded from the indexing and alike.

You can manage those folders at `Settings/Preferences | Project | Directories` (as well as right click in Poject View panel and `Mark Directory As` submenu).

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/directories.html?search=directo

---

The folder/file name colors -- those are VCS status. You can check and change it at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | File Status`.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/file-status-highlights.html?search=file%20status

Comment: Great, yes, we can set our folders to be the same colors now, but still on his computer, when he drops a folder from Windows Explorer into a brown folder, it reacts differently for various brown folders:

1. for some brown folders, it adds the pasted folder to SVN automatically (although we would like PHP Storm to ask, like it does on my computer)

2. for other brown folders, it does not add the pasted folder to SVN, and changes the text of the folder to gray, yet the folder color is not red.

Comment: There seems to be another level of settings somewhere which determines (1) if PHP Storms asks upon pasting into the folder tree if you want to add that resource to SVN, and (2) if the text of the folder is gray or not, independent of whether the color of the folder icon is brown or red.

Comment: Maybe `.svnignore` or something like this? I'm not SVN or VCS expert at all, unfortunately. I may only direct you to this manual: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Version+Control+Systems+Support+in+PhpStorm

Comment: On my end, I can only change File colors, not folders'

Comment: @CarlesAlcolea, Yes, **File** status colors apply to **files**. For folders you may need to enable `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Version Control | Show directories with changed descendants` option.